# AWS KVS stream issue with Angular

Tags: video-streaming, hlsl, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I used AWS KVS with Angular 9, When I am trying to get stream on PlaybackMode "ON_DEMAND", stream coming as a res is not equals to the TimestampRange I have sent. If I am sending TimestampRange of 1 hour, am getting only 12-16 mins of stream.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Would it be worth showing your code/config in the question? Formatting tools are available.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.